# How to wrap text around picture

Tags: html, css

How do you wrap text around an image in HTML and CSS? I have an image and a text next to it, but it would not go below the image. how could I make text go around the image? What would be the best way for the text and image to looks when we view on a phone screen.

I cannot any useful way on the internet. I am quite new to html

Thank you.

here is my code bellow

```css
.catim{
    shape-outside: square(50%);
}

.cat{
    position: flex;
    top: 65%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(00%,2%);
    padding: 120px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 255, 13, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.cat .aboutcat h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    color:rgb(188, 206, 27);
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>cat</title>
        
        
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styletest.css">
        

    </head>
    <body>      
        <div class="cat">              
            <img src="https://www.pexels.com/photo/selective-focus-photography-of-orange-tabby-cat-1170986/" width="250" height="250" class="catim">            
            <div class="aboutcat">
                <h1>About Cat</h1>
                <p>Hi, This is a cat <br><br>
                    The cat (Felis catus) is a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal.[1][2] It is the only domesticated species in the family Felidae and is often referred to as the domestic cat to distinguish it from the wild members of the family.[4] A cat can either be a house cat, a farm cat or a feral cat; the latter ranges freely and avoids human contact.[5] Domestic cats are valued by humans for companionship and their ability to hunt rodents. About 60 cat breeds are recognized by various cat registries.[6]
The cat is similar in anatomy to the other felid species: it has a strong flexible body, quick reflexes, sharp teeth and retractable claws adapted to killing small prey. Its night vision and sense of smell are well developed. Cat communication includes vocalizations like meowing, purring, trilling, hissing, growling and grunting as well as cat-specific body language. A predator that is most active at dawn and dusk, the cat is a solitary hunter but a social species. It can hear sounds too faint or too high in frequency for human ears, such as those made by mice and other small mammals.[7] It secretes and perceives pheromones.[8]
Female domestic cats can have kittens from spring to late autumn, with litter sizes often ranging from two to five kittens.[9] Domestic cats are bred and shown at events as registered pedigreed cats, a hobby known as cat fancy. Failure to control breeding of pet cats by spaying and neutering, as well as abandonment of pets, resulted in large numbers of feral cats worldwide, contributing to the extinction of entire bird, mammal, and reptile species, and evoking population control.[10]
            </div>           
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add `float: left;` to `.catim` and remove `display: flex;` from `.cat`

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I tried but nothing happened

Comment: It worked for me - https://ibb.co/NjDGT42. What result do you want to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

No need for "flex" or "shape-outside" properties if you just want the text to wrap around a square photo:

```css
.cat {
  padding: 120px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 255, 13, 0.5);
  resize: both;
  overflow: hide;
}

.catim {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.cat .aboutcat h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: rgb(188, 206, 27);
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat">              
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514888286974-6c03e2ca1dba?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Y2F0fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" class="catim">            
            <div class="aboutcat">
                <h1>About Cat</h1>
                <p>Hi, This is a cat <br><br>
                    The cat (Felis catus) is a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal.[1][2] It is the only domesticated species in the family Felidae and is often referred to as the domestic cat to distinguish it from the wild members of the family.[4] A cat can either be a house cat, a farm cat or a feral cat; the latter ranges freely and avoids human contact.[5] Domestic cats are valued by humans for companionship and their ability to hunt rodents. About 60 cat breeds are recognized by various cat registries.[6]
The cat is similar in anatomy to the other felid species: it has a strong flexible body, quick reflexes, sharp teeth and retractable claws adapted to killing small prey. Its night vision and sense of smell are well developed. Cat communication includes vocalizations like meowing, purring, trilling, hissing, growling and grunting as well as cat-specific body language. A predator that is most active at dawn and dusk, the cat is a solitary hunter but a social species. It can hear sounds too faint or too high in frequency for human ears, such as those made by mice and other small mammals.[7] It secretes and perceives pheromones.[8]
Female domestic cats can have kittens from spring to late autumn, with litter sizes often ranging from two to five kittens.[9] Domestic cats are bred and shown at events as registered pedigreed cats, a hobby known as cat fancy. Failure to control breeding of pet cats by spaying and neutering, as well as abandonment of pets, resulted in large numbers of feral cats worldwide, contributing to the extinction of entire bird, mammal, and reptile species, and evoking population control.[10]
            </div>           
       </div>
```

You could use `shape-outside` for this effect:

```css
.cat {
  padding: 120px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 255, 13, 0.5);
  resize: both;
  overflow: hide;
}

.catim {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle();
  shape-outside: circle();
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.cat .aboutcat h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: rgb(188, 206, 27);
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514888286974-6c03e2ca1dba?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Y2F0fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" width="250" height="250" class="catim">
  <div class="aboutcat">
    <h1>About Cat</h1>
    <p>Hi, This is a cat <br><br>
      The cat (Felis catus) is a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal.[1][2] It is the only domesticated species in the family Felidae and is often referred to as the domestic cat to distinguish it from the wild members of the family.[4] A cat can either be a house cat, a farm cat or a feral cat; the latter ranges freely and avoids human contact.[5] Domestic cats are valued by humans for companionship and their ability to hunt rodents. About 60 cat breeds are recognized by various cat registries.[6]
      The cat is similar in anatomy to the other felid species: it has a strong flexible body, quick reflexes, sharp teeth and retractable claws adapted to killing small prey. Its night vision and sense of smell are well developed. Cat communication includes vocalizations like meowing, purring, trilling, hissing, growling and grunting as well as cat-specific body language. A predator that is most active at dawn and dusk, the cat is a solitary hunter but a social species. It can hear sounds too faint or too high in frequency for human ears, such as those made by mice and other small mammals.[7] It secretes and perceives pheromones.[8]
      Female domestic cats can have kittens from spring to late autumn, with litter sizes often ranging from two to five kittens.[9] Domestic cats are bred and shown at events as registered pedigreed cats, a hobby known as cat fancy. Failure to control breeding of pet cats by spaying and neutering, as well as abandonment of pets, resulted in large numbers of feral cats worldwide, contributing to the extinction of entire bird, mammal, and reptile species, and evoking population control.[10]
  </div>
</div>
```

Wrapping text around the image on all sides it tricky (and there may be a better way to do it than the following) but you could use floats and pseudo elements to achieve this effect:

```css
.page-wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.img-cat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text {
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
}

.text-left {
  float: left;
}

.text-right {
  float: right;
}

.text-right {
  float: right;
}

.text:before {
  content: "";
  width: 115px;
  height: 225px;
}

.text-left:before {
  float: right;
}

.text-right:before {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514888286974-6c03e2ca1dba?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Y2F0fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" class="img-cat">
  <div class="text text-left">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text text-right">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think it's worth mentioning that you can now do some pretty cool stuff with `shape-outside` and `clip-path` such as the following:

```css
.img-cat {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  object-fit: cover;
  shape-outside: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.text-left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514888286974-6c03e2ca1dba?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Y2F0fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" class="img-cat">
<div class="text text-left">
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
<div class="text text-right">
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I just have a few questions. Without the position how to I make the box in the middle?

Comment: I added a snippet that shows an example of a way to have text around a centered image as well as some other fun text-wrapping examples.

Answer (score 0):

To make the time below the image, remove

```css
display : flex
```

from .cat, and add

```css
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
```

to .catim if you want to align it to the center.

To wrap the text around the image, use

```css
float: left
```

on .catim.